# OnePage Scroll just for the first section?

Tags: scroll, onepage-scroll

I want to use OnePage Scroll like this:

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
or
http://schliflo.github.io/OnePageR/

the thing is: i just want that the first page scroll like this.
after that it has to scroll normal. i want to put much content on the second section. so it need to scroll normally. how could i do this?

if i put "overflow:scoll" on second section it scrolls normaly down but not up.

need help, thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: i tried: overflow:scoll on second section. it worked. but up scrolling doesnt work. i have no idea what i can do else. i'm bad in js.

Answer (score 0):

I think you best option is to put div in the section you want to scroll, make that div the same size as the screen and give it the property overflow scroll. This way your section will not be bigger than the page but it can still scroll.

Comment: i've already tried it. look here: http://codepen.io/kevkev/full/dMowpB/ .. but the thing is it normally scrolls down but not up!

Answer (score 0):

i found the perfect solution:

on downloading full packet of http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/
there is "scrolling inside sections"

Answer (score 0):

I am sure this is what you are looking for

http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/oneSection.html